# substr giving wrong value - javascript

Tags: javascript, string, substr

For some reason, when I do the following:

```
var input = 'focus name (tag1 tag2 OTHER,STUFF) focus 2 (MORE)';
var openParen = input.indexOf('(');
var closeParen = input.indexOf(')');
var parenStr = input.substr(openParen + 1, closeParen - 1);
```

I expect `parenStr` to equal `"tag1 tag2 OTHER,STUFF"`.

Instead, I'm getting it as `"tag1 tag2 OTHER,STUFF) focus 2 "`. Can anyone explain this to me?I feel like I'm going crazy haha, I've tried manually entering:

```
input.substr(openParen + 1, 32)
```

but it gives the exact same result. I've used `.substr()` tons of times before and never run into this kind of error before, I must be missing something.

Comment: The second argument is a length! Use the difference between the last and first positions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You meant to use substring:

`input.substring(openParen + 1, closeParen);`

`substring` takes a start and end index as parameters. `substr` takes a start index and length parameter, which is not what you intended.

Answer (score -2):

```
var input = 'focus name (tag1 tag2 OTHER,STUFF) focus 2 (MORE)';
var openParen = input.indexOf('(');
var closeParen = input.indexOf(')');
alert(input.substr(openParen + 1, closeParen - openParen - 1));
```

Comment: technically correct, but it's pretty clear the OP meant `substring` and not `substr`.

Comment: @Afforess so what? the result is the same.

Comment: I said you were technically correct. There is no debate here.

Comment: @Sacho I do not think so.